# Bing maps api web control, turn off traffic information

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

I'm using the Bing maps v8 web control and I'm wondering how I can get the directions manager to stop putting traffic updates into the directions? I've tried the following, but maybe that is just for the map?

```
    Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Traffic', function () {
        var manager = new Microsoft.Maps.Traffic.TrafficManager(map);
        manager.show();
        manager.hideIncidents();
    });
```

Here's a screenshot to provide some more information on what I'm seeing:

[image]

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide more details on the issue you are trying to solve. It's not clear. What traffic updates? If it is the warnings in the instructions, set the displayStepWarnings directions render option to false.

Comment: I added a screenshot to give a better idea of what I'm seeing. I want to get rid of these traffic comments in the point to point directions as they are not pertinent (as this is a trip planning tool for future use). Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to remove this information from the built in instructions UI. You can however, access the raw route instruction data and create your own instructions UI and have full control over rendering.